# Examine Bash variables with dynamic names

Tags: bash, variables, eval, associative-array, variable-names

I'm trying to read from Bash variables for which I know name suffixes, but I want to iterate through the prefixes.

I give an example below:

```
var1_name="variable1"
var1_size="2"
var2_name="variable2"
var2_size="3"
vars=(var1 var2)

for v in "${vars[@]}"
do
    echo $v_name
    echo $v_size
done
```

and I'd want the output to look like follows:

```
variable1
2
variable2
3
```

Is there any to do this with Bash?
I have tried with `eval` and associative arrays, but I still can't find a way to examine an already defined variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below works for me. You need to construct the variable first and then evaluate it using exclamation.

```
var1_name="variable1"
var1_size="2"
var2_name="variable2"
var2_size="3"
vars=("var1" "var2")

for v in "${vars[@]}"
do
    name=${v}_name
    size=${v}_size
    echo ${!name}
    echo ${!size}
done
```

O/P

```
variable1
2
variable2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

[auhuman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307095/45375) solves your problem exactly as asked.

Here's an alternative that doesn't require you to specify the name prefixes in an array first, *assuming that all variables of interest have names with the same prefix*, such as `var`:

```
for name in "${!var@}"  # Loop over all variables whose names start with 'var'.
do
    [[ $name =~ ^var[0-9]+_(name|size)$ ]] || continue # Ignore unrelated names.
    echo "${!name}" # Use variable indirection to print the variable's value. 
done
```

- The code uses *two* forms of Bash **variable indirection**, all based on syntax `${!...}`:

  - `"${!var@}"` is the ***literal*-based *list* form**: it expands to the *list* (array) of the *names* of all defined variables whose names have *literal* prefix `var` (whose names *start with* `var`), if any. Since only a literal is allowed to precede `@`, using a pattern such as
    <del>`"${!var[0-9]_@}"`</del> for more sophisticated matching does *not* work, unfortunately.

    - Example: `for varName in "${!HOST@}"; do echo "$varName"; done`
      yields `HOSTNAME` and `HOSTTYPE`, for instance.
    - The related `${!var*}` syntax (*without* double quotes) seems to work the same.
      (Curiously, the `man` page claims that the 1st char. of the `$IFS` value is used to concatenate the matching names, which would only work as expected in a `for` loop if that 1st char. is a *whitespace* char. (which is true of the `$IFS` default value, which starts with a space), but in practice a *space* is always used, irrespective of the value of `$IFS`; verify with `(IFS=@; echo ${!HOST*})`)
  - `${!name}`, the ***variable*-based *scalar* form**, expands to the value of the variable whose *name* is stored as the value of `$name`.

    - Example: `var='value'; name='var'; echo ${!name}` yields `value`.
    - Note: With a trick (*not* used above), you can use indirection to **get an *array*'s values too**, namely by appending the all-indices index expression `[@]` to the name of the variable to reference indirectly; e.g.:
      `arr=( one two three ); name='arr[@]'; echo "${!name}"`
      yields `one two three`; accessing a specific element this way (e.g., `name='arr[1]'`) works too, but extracting a *range* of elements does *not* (e.g., <del>`name='arr[@]: 0:2'`</del>).
  - There is also an ***array-index* *list* form** - *not* used above - which expands to the list (array) of indices / keys of a given array / associative array.

    - Example: `arr=( one two three ); echo "${!arr[@]}"`
      yields `0 1 2`, the implicit sequential indices of the array.
    - It works analogously with explicitly assigned indices (e.g.,
      `arr=( [10]=one two three ); echo "${!arr[@]}"`) or, in Bash v4+, with associative arrays (although, as is the nature of associative arrays, the keys are not guaranteed to be listed in the order they were defined; e.g.,
      `declare -A aarr=( [one]=1 [two]=2 ); echo "${!aarr[@]}"`).
- `[[ $v =~ ^var[0-9]+_(name|size)$ ]]` uses the `=~` operator to match the variable name at hand against the extended regular expression on the RHS to determine if it is a name of interest.

Comment: I actually don't use the names var1, var2... It's a bit different, but it could be very useful for similar things I'm doing in that script, Thanks!

Comment: @OfriRips: Understood, and thanks. I've made it clearer that my answer assumes a shared name prefix (and I've added an overview of variable indirection). Thanks for coming back and accepting auhuman's answer. Please also consider revisiting your old questions to see if answers there deserve being accepted.